# Visual studio 2017 publishing got stuck

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC project (into folder), however the process is getting stuck here :
[image]

I assume, that today publishing process was updated, because yesterday it has different interface and worked fine. I have tried to create new publish profile but I cant find any property to do this, like it was before, and all guides are referenced to previous versions.

For now I have tried to rebuild my project and restart VS and my pc - didn't help.

Comment: What's your ISP?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub What? Where did you find it?

Comment: What's the company that provide internet to your current location?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub why does it matter? o0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this tweet:

> [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) [@Orange](https://twitter.com/orange) http://portal.azure.com and all the Azure Web Apps seems to be down for the Orange customers. What's happening?— Lucas Libis (@LucasLibis) [28 juin 2017](https://twitter.com/LucasLibis/status/879986577090465792)

You're not the only one in trouble. The solution is to use another connection for now...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it in this way:

1. Open *Solution Explorer*
2. Go to your project and open the *Properties* sub-node
3. Delete the *PublishProfiles* folder
4. Reopen the publish menu and create a new publish profile

Answer (score 0):

[image: This option must be set on the release.]

This option must be set on the release